# Could not acces to home directory /home/user01: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, permission-denied

I created a new username called user01. Then, I used usermod to grant permissions with another user.
After that, I logged out and login as user 02 but can access to /home/user01

```
[user02@SRV01 ~]$ cd /home/user01/
-bash: cd: /home/user01/: Permission denied
```

I checked the directory and permisions of /home/user01 and user by this commands:

```
[user02@SRV01 ~]$ ls -ltrh / | grep home
drwxr-xr-x.  10 root root 4,0K feb 19  2019 home

[user02@SRV01 ~]$ ls -ltrh /home | grep user01
drwxrwxr-x+ 17 user01   user01   4,0K nov 26 18:14 user01

root@SRV01 /home # id user02
uid=509(user02) gid=500(user01) grupos=500(user01),511(user02)
```

What's the exactly problem? Thank's in advance

Comment: try using ACL https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91488/allow-a-user-to-read-some-other-users-home-directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plus sign at the end in the listing of user01 directory implies the use of ACL. (Access Control Lists)

For more information on the permissions, use getfacl command.

That should show that the user02 has read-execute access on the directory user01.

If the appropriate setting is not there, you'll need to do that using setfacl.

For example,

```
setfacl -m u:user02:x user01
setfacl -m u:user02:r user01
```

I hope this works!
You can play around with them after reading more on man page of the getfacl/setfacl commands.

Comment: thanks. That's possible to know why in my env can't access previous to execute this commands?

Comment: getfacl should give you the answer for that one. The user02 should be listed in its output, for having permissions.